# How To Add a License Key To Your Vuforia App

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

[This is place to me fill my license](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2omzc.png)

I did follow this guide [link](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/How-To-add-a-License-Key-to-your-Vuforia-App). But I don't know why my app don't have place to fill license. Please help me!
Thank you anyway!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could click Vuforia tab on the menu, then click Configuration.
Please refer to https://i.stack.imgur.com/5THvM.png